# Windows Phone 8.1 - MVVMLight - Why is EventToCommad not working?

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvm-light, windows-phone-8.1, eventtocommand

I am not able to use EventToCommand in my Windows Phone 8.1 App.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP8"
```

I tried it also with assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP81...

```
<controls:PivotItem Name="pivotItem">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectServiceCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex,                                 ElementName=pivotItem}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <!-- other stuff  -->
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I get the following erros:

- The member "Triggers" is not recognized or is not accessible.
- Unknown type 'EventTrigger' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity'
- Error    2   The attachable property 'Triggers' was not found in type 'Interaction'.
  ...

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you aiming at Silverlight, or WinRT (Universal Apps) kind of Windows Phone 8.1?

If you have chosen the second option, then in this [blog post](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/) MVVM Light author explains the lack of support for EventToCommand - basically in WinRT there's already a mechanism similiar to the EventToCommand - Behaviours.

Comment: Do you know the solution regarding the first situation (targeting Silverlight 8.1)? I created a new WP 8.1 project and added mvvm light trough NuGet but "EventToCommand" from "GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command" was not found. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Windows Phone 8.1**

[Windows 8.1 Behavior SDK: How to use InvokeAction with InputConverter to pass arguments to a Command](http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/windows-8-1-behavior-sdk-how-to-use-invokeaction-with-inputconverter-to-pass-arguments-to-a-command/)

Microsoft has developed it's own EventToCommand functionality. It's located in Behaviors SDK. Someone on stackoverflow told to get this SDK via Nuget. If you can't find the package in NuGet - get it in `Add reference dialog`.

[image]
(My "Add reference" dialog may differ from original because of `Productivity Power Tools` extension)

Here is example of simple usage:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons, Mode=OneWay}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DisplayPersonCommand}" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading my WP8.0 app to use MVVMLight 5.0+ disabled the EventToCommand behavior, my search for a solution brought me to this [blog post](http://wpfplayground.com/2014/01/18/invokecommandaction-with-eventargs-as-command-parameter/) that provided source code for implementing a Custom Command Action that will pass the event args as the parameter.  Implementing the code returned my app to working order!!

Hopes this helps you out :D